# How to get odd ratio for the result of pairwise comparison for binomial GLMM?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, glmm, odds-ratio, lsmeans

I have run a binomial generalised linear mixed model (GLMM) via the lme4 package in R. The optimal model of mine is from this syntax: fm1 <- glmer (answer~ (1|subj) + (1|item) + seeconversationmask, data=analysis1, family=binomial, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))

I have three independent variables. They're all categorical. The first variable has two categories; the second one has two categories and the last one has three categories. The optimal model is the model with three-way interaction which means all variables are needed to explain the finding.

And this is the example of output I've got from emmeans package for pairwise comparison to see if there are significant differences in each contrast:
[image]

The example of my interpretations is 'The participants received significantly lower score in ao, clear, dm context than ao, con, dm context (b = -4.74, SE = 0.60, p < 0.01).'

However, after running the syntax for odd ratio, it gives me this:
[image]

So we can see that the results from odd ratio formula doesn't fit with the results from pairwise comparison. Hence, I cannot use the odd ratio from this formula as it doesn't give me odd ratio for each pair of contrast. Do you have any other solution? Is there other way to get odd ratio for each pair of contrast for three independent variables? Sorry for posting this question again. The first time hasn't been answered.